# Reduced Row Echelon form is unique - how is this step in the proof a contradiction?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

In A First Course in Linear Algebra, the author's first step in the [proof](http://linear.pugetsound.edu/html/section-RREF.html#theorem-RREFU) (note, the hyperlink on the page must be clicked to open a dropdown with the necessary information) which shows that RREF is unique opens as follows:

*First Step. Suppose that $d_1 < d^{\prime}_1$. Then,*

$$
\begin{align*}
1
&=\matrix[B]_{1d_1}
&\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\delta_{1k}[{C}]_{kd_1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\delta_{1k}(0)
&&d_1<d^\prime_1\\
&=0
\end{align*}
$$

He then finishes this step by saying,

*The entries of $C$ are all zero since they are left and below of the leading 1 in row 1 and column $d^{\prime}_1$ of $C$. This is a contradiction, so we know that $d_1 \ge d^{\prime}_1$. By an entirely similar argument, reversing the roles of $B$ and $C$, we could conclude that $d_1 \le d^{\prime}_1$. Together this means that $d_1 = d^{\prime}_1$.*

So, what I'm trying to figure out is...what exactly is so contradictory about this? I understand the definition of RREF, but this explanation is slightly vague.

Answer (score 0):

The contradiction is the conclusion that $1=0$. In other words, if we assume $d_1<d_1'$, then $1=0$; therefore it cannot be true that $d_1<d_1'$, and we must have $d_1\ge d_1'$.

The statement "The entries of $C$ are all zero since they are left and below of the leading 1 in row 1 and column $d_1'$ of $C$" is not itself contradictory; it's justifying why $[C]_{kd_1}=0$ for every $k$.